# How to display/register widget only on post pages in custom plugin

Tags: widgets

I want to display a custom widget in my custom plugin ONLY on post pages. How can I do this without using a third party plugin or editing the theme files?

is_single() does not work in the widget method of the Widget class.

Comment: Why doesn’t is_single work? Could you show the code of that widget and do you use any custom loops at single post template?

Answer (score 0):

Display your widget only on post pages by adding `if ( !is_single() or is_page()) {  return;}` at the start of your Widget's `function widget()`

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    if ( !is_single() or is_page()) {  return;}

    // rest of code
}
```